# Binary relations vs non-Binary realtions in database design

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relation

### What is the difference between n-ary relation and binary relations ?

- What are pros and cons ?
- Which one is better for a relational database design ?

Comment: Which one is better?  It depends on the case.  And you would be better off asking about n-ary relationships than about n-ary relations.

Comment: Yes, my purpose was relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N-ary relations describe relations of any arity - unary, binary, ternary, etc.

Simple mathematical examples of such relations would be sets of points in n-dimensional cartesian space.  For example:

- A unary relation could represent any set of points on a number line.
- A binary relation could represent any set of points on a plane, or any set of intervals on a number line.
- A ternary relation could represent any set of points in 3D space.
- A quarternary relation could represent any set of points in 4D space, or any set of lines on a plane.

Numbers aren't the only domain we can relate.  We can relate any sets of values - names, colors, dates, etc.  Relations can represent any predicate we want:

- A unary relation could represent a set of user rights
- A binary relation could associate a set of user names and passwords
- A ternary relation could associate a set of user names, rights and access levels

The relational model of data is built on this idea, and the fact that relations can be easily represented as tables following certain rules:

- Each column has a unique name and is associated with a domain
- Every cell holds exactly one value from the domain of its column
- Order of rows and columns don't matter
- No duplicate rows

One of the advantages of relational databases is that they are able to use n-ary relations, which makes it easy to record any data as relations.  Relations can be composed into bigger relations - logically, facts can be combined to derive other facts which are implied but not recorded.  Thus, relational databases make it easier to get more value from your data, and they're a significant step on the path to deductive databases.

In the relational model of data, there's no preference for binary or other arities.  We use what we need, but we like to keep relations simple, since they're easier to manipulate and combine that way.

I recommend `Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals` by Lex de Haan and Toon Koppelaars for an in-depth exploration of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment that you meant to ask about relationships rather than relations, I decided to add a second answer focusing on relationships as defined in the entity-relationship model:

N-ary relationships describe relationships of any arity - binary, ternary, etc.  The arity describes either the number of roles in the relationship <sub>[1]</sub> (regardless of whether they refer to the same of different entity sets), or the number of different entity sets.

Binary relationships are the most familiar.  For example, `<supplier> supplies <product>`.  Examples of ternary relationships could be `<supplier> supplies <product> in <region>`, or `<student> takes <course> with <teacher>`.

True unary relationships (a relationship having a single role) aren't found in ER models.  These would be indistinguishable from entity sets or subtypes.  Instead, some authors use the term to refer to binary relations on a single entity set.

Each role in a relationship can have an associated cardinality, referring the to the number of entities in that role that can be associated with each combination of entities in the other roles of the relationship.  This is commonly seen in binary relationships which are broadly classified in terms of upper bounds: 1-to-1, 1-to-many or many-to-many.  In n-ary relationships, 1:M:N or M:N:P:Q relationships are possible.

Relationships in the ER model are represented as tables (or relationship relations, in ER terminology) where the primary key is a composite key consisting of the keys of each of the entity sets involved in the relationship with cardinality higher than 1.  Relationships can have attributes (non-prime columns), these aren't counted towards the arity of the relationship.

Relations with common determinants are often denormalized in relational database designs.  In the case of 1-to-many binary relationships, this means recording the relationship in the same table as the entity on the many side.  For example, a relationship between employee and their managers (`employee_id -> manager_id`) can be recorded by including `manager_id` in the employee table.

In the network data model, only binary relationships are allowed.  Translating an ER model to the network model requires reifying n-ary relationships with n > 2 into entities with n binary relationships.  This additionally requires the introduction of surrogate identifiers and unique constraints that would be handled by a composite key in an ER model.

As for your question to compare pros and cons - in ER, as in relational, we use whatever arity relationships are appropriate to model our data.

If instead you want to know how data models based on n-ary relationships compare to those based on binary relationships only, I suggest you do a search for `access path independence`.

<sub>[1]</sub> I prefer to count the roles, since it's consistent with the term in the relational model.